# Deploying OSGI bundles through Maven

Tags: java, maven-2, osgi, equinox

Is there any way to deploy osgi bundles in a running equinox container through maven commands?

Any plugin available for the same?

I am posting this question after a lot of searching. I found that PAX-RUNNER could be useful. But it is working good with felix and not for equinox. Also it seems that pax runner starts a new instance of the container every time. I want my osgi bundles to be deployed in a running equinox environment and that needs to be done through maven commands.

Answer (score 0):

Ouch. The deployment *must* be done from within the running OSGi framework. Now, some frameworks expose facilities to do that from the outside, but if you need something that works consistently across frameworks you will need to write it yourself, an the choreography between the components will be nasty - think OSGi bundle that exposes f.e. an HTTP endpoint that acceppts POSTed bundles for installation, and a maven plugin that can send them. If you do write it, don't keep it for yourself.

Comment: Actually the OSGi Alliance have recently published an RFC for a RESTful administration interface, including the ability to post new bundles, update bundles, etc. However it's only an RFC so far, there is no implementation yet that I know of.

Comment: @NeilBartlett Oooh, nice! Thanks for the tip, reading up on it right now.